# How to provide Nexus path in Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

I am using maven for my project and need to provide a Nexus path after providing GroupId, ArtifactId and Version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
    <version>myversion</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.def</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
    <version>myversion</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.ghi</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
    <version>myversion</version>
</dependency>
```

**My Nexus path -** https://nexus/content/repositories/

**Artifact present in path -** https:/mynexusdomain/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/**com/org/abc/myartifactid/MySnapshotVersion/plugins/MyRequiredJars**

**Settings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/settings/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <localRepository>D:/Maven_repo</localRepository>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>          
      <name>Nexus</name>
<url>http://NexusDomain/nexus/content/repositories/myrepo/myrepo1/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

Here, as per the pom file, I can mention the groupid (com.org.abc), artifactid (myartifactid). Is there any possible ways to mention the path after artifactid in nexus url ie., to take artifact inside that particular folder ?

Any inputs would be really appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: How have you configured nexus in your settings.xml ?

Comment: Updated a snippet of my setting.xml above

Comment: You don't have a group in nexus which combines snapshots/internal releases/central mirror ... also you should using `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` to force consumptions only from Nexus.... and it looks strange `../repositories/myrepo/myrepo1/*` does that mean there is a specific repositories for only a project??

Comment: Not specific to a project. My file has to read artifact from https:/mynexusdomain/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/<GroupID>/<ArtifactID>/<NeedToMentionSomeotherPathHere>. After ArtifacID, how can we mention remaining path in pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't use folders inside Nexus. Only groupId, artifactId, version. If you need to load other JARs, load them with their own respective groupId, artifactId, version.

Comment: can we provide nexus url inside pom.xml to mention the dependencies ? If yes, can you pls provide a sample ?

Comment: You can add it to the `<repositories>`, but this usually not done, but instead you put repositories into the `settings.xml`.